# publishing zend website issue on goDaddy.com

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm trying to move my zend application from local to remote.After I uploaded all of my folders  on my GoDaddy host this is **my folders structure** :

```
/html
 /application
  /configs
  /controllers
  /models
  /views

 bootstrap.php

 /library
 /public
  /css
  /images
  /js
  .htaccess
  index.php
```

my **index.php** :

```
// Define path to application directory

defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
|| define('APPLICATION_PATH',realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));

// Define application environment

defined('APPLICATION_ENV')|| define('APPLICATION_ENV',
(getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV'): 'production'));

//add library directory to include path

set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/library',dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) .
'/application/models',dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . 
'/application/forms',dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/application/views/scripts',
get_include_path())));

/** Zend_Application */

require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

// Create application, bootstrap, and run

$application = new Zend_Application(
APPLICATION_ENV,
APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini');

$application->bootstrap()->run();
```

Now if I try to go type this URL : "www.mysite.com/public/index/index" **I receive this error** :

```
The requested URL /public/index/index/ was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying 
to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

And if I just type : "www.mysite.com/public/" **I receive this warning** :

```
Warning: require_once(/home/content/66/6902756/html/application/Bootstrap.php
[function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
in /home/content/66/6902756/html/library/Zend/Application.php on line 320

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening
required '/home/content/66/6902756/html/application/Bootstrap.php'
(include_path='/home/content/66/6902756/html/application/../library:
/home/content/66/6902756/html/library:
/home/content/66/6902756/html/application/models:
/home/content/66/6902756/html/application/forms:
/home/content/66/6902756/html/application/views/scripts:
.:/usr/local/php5/lib/php')
in /home/content/66/6902756/html/library/Zend/Application.php on line 320
```

In local everything was working properly

**UPDATE**
In my index.php I tried :

```
//it output "exists"
echo  file_exists( '/home/content/66/6902756/html/application/Bootstrap.php' )?'exists':'no file found';

//where '/home/content/66/6902756/html' is my absolute hosting path
```

thanks

Comment: try `www.mysite.com/index/index`

Comment: Have you pasted the zend-library to library folder.....?

Comment: @NAVEED not working.
@Pushpendra yes I have

Comment: What is your root directory in `httpd.conf` file ?? And also try `www.mysite.com/public/index.php`

Comment: My root directory should be "/home/content/66/6902756/html" but I don't think I have access to the httpd.conf file.

Comment: In your edit with file_exists tests you forgot the starting / for absolute path '/home/content/66/6902756/html/application/Bootstrap.php' so you cannot have 'exists' answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll wager that a major part of your problem is that you're using `\` in your include path. Try replacing those with the constant `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`.  Personally, I would get rid of all of those `dirname(dirname(__FILE__))`. Instead use the built in `APPLICATION_PATH`:

```
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
dirname( APPLICATION_PATH ) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'library', //note one exception
APPLICATION_PATH. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'models',
APPLICATION_PATH. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'forms',
APPLICATION_PATH. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'views'. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .'scripts',
get_include_path())));
```

Comment: I tried with forward slashes (im on linux) but nothing same result. I also tried to echo out "dirname(dirname(_FILE_))" and it's giving :"/home/content/66/6902756/html"

Comment: 1. Can you test this: echo file_exists( '/home/content/66/6902756/html/application/Bootstrap.php' )?'exists':'no file found'; 2. Can you confirm that your APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini' doesn't accidentally have a 'bootstrap' property?

Comment: you were right My application.ini had a bootstrap reference without capitol letter (bootstrap.php)..is windows case insenitive (I didnt have problems in local)?

Comment: last thing: now when I type : "http://www.mysite/public/" I have my index page output ..But if I type:"http://www.mysite/public/index/index/" i receive a  404 Not Found why?